# Pandas resampling with custom volume weighted aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I'm trying to do a volume weighted price aggregation based on a 5 second timestep for which I have multiple datapoints. I can get simple mean and sum aggregations for individual fields by passing a dict of aggregation types. However, to generate a volume weighted aggregation I need to use both the pricing and volume fields to generate this for each step.

```
                    TS          P           Q
D           
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673574.0   0.164012
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673954.0   0.006000
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673967.0   0.005808
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673949.0   0.040000
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673573.0   0.159234
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673569.0   0.007000
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673949.0   0.100000
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673569.0   0.008000
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673949.0   0.033000
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1514764800  1673346.0   0.033000
2018-01-01 00:00:01 1514764801  1673967.0   0.212200
2018-01-01 00:00:02 1514764802  1673954.0   0.006765
2018-01-01 00:00:03 1514764803  1673950.0   0.012000
2018-01-01 00:00:03 1514764803  1673955.0   0.005700
2018-01-01 00:00:03 1514764803  1673642.0   0.031197
2018-01-01 00:00:03 1514764803  1673949.0   0.067654
```

The volume weighting formula should simply be a cumulative sum of quantity x price divided by the total quantity for the period.

Is there a way to do this with a custom aggregation using both the price and quantity series to return a VWAP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.apply` you can write any custom aggregation function you want.

```
def vwap(data):
    return (data.P * data.Q).sum() / data.Q.sum()
```

When using a grouper, you can apply it like this:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="5s")).apply(vwap)
```

With resampling, `.apply` can be used as well:

```
df.resample("5s").apply(vwap)
```

Comment: `df.resample('5s').agg({'P':'last', 'Q':'sum'}) `
is my current approach and I suppose I could use yours to do a join of the VWAP values to the common Datetime Index, I am just curious if there is a way to do this natively with resample as well?

Comment: You should be able to use `.apply` the same way when resampling. I've edited the answer.

Comment: For me, the command doesn't work with "resample" --> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Volume'
. Do you know what I can do?

Comment: @Baobab it seems you are trying to look up a field "Volume" in a Series (not a DataFrame), which is unrelated to trying to resample something. I suggest you create a new question, with a fully reproducible example of your data.