# Pandas DatetimeIndex TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I attempting to do what was done here: [Pandas resampling with custom volume weighted aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879282/pandas-resampling-with-custom-volume-weighted-aggregation) but am hitting a TypeError with my Index.

I have data like:

```
                         Dates       P   Q
0   2020-09-07 01:20:24.738686  7175.0  21
1   2020-09-07 01:45:27.540590  7150.0   7
2   2020-09-07 03:48:49.120607  7125.0   4
3   2020-09-07 04:45:50.972042  7125.0   6
4   2020-09-07 05:36:23.139612  7125.0   2
```

I check the type using `print(df.dtypes)` which returns:

```
Dates    datetime64[ns]
P               float64
Q                 int64
dtype: object
```

I then set the index to be the dates using
`df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Dates']))`

And then I drop the Dates column to make it easier to read using `df = df.drop(['Dates'], axis=1)`

This gives me

```
                                 P   Q
Dates                                 
2020-09-07 01:20:24.738686  7175.0  21
2020-09-07 01:45:27.540590  7150.0   7
2020-09-07 03:48:49.120607  7125.0   4
2020-09-07 04:45:50.972042  7125.0   6
2020-09-07 05:36:23.139612  7125.0   2
```

I then attempt to resample:

```
def vwap(data):
    price = data.P
    quantity = data.Q

    top = sum(price * quantity)
    bottom = sum(quantity)

    return top / bottom

df2 = df.resample("5h",axis=1).apply(vwap)
```

This results in the error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Looking at other stack overflow entries with similar names, their issues are mostly that the datetime only looks like a datetime, but isn't actually formatted as a datetime. This isn't the case here as we can see earlier with that the Dates column has type `datetime64[ns]`

Further, if I do `print(df.index.dtype)`, I get:

```
datetime64[ns]
```

Any suggestions? Happy to clarify anything or provide more code if it would help.

Comment: It's because you resample over `axis=1`, remove that argument and it should work.

Comment: @Erfan That allows the resample to start attempting to work, but is now gives the error `'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'P''`. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how the resampling works but when I do `print(data)` I get: `2020-09-07 01:20:24.738686    7175.0
2020-09-07 01:45:27.540590    7150.0
2020-09-07 03:48:49.120607    7125.0
2020-09-07 04:45:50.972042    7125.0
Name: P, dtype: float64`. One would imagine I need the row of data (which I believe is what `axis, 1`, gave me, rather than the column (which I believe is what I'm getting without stating the axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `axis=1` argument and using `pd.Grouper` works:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="5h")).apply(vwap)
```

```
Dates
2020-09-07 00:00:00    7157.236842
2020-09-07 05:00:00    7125.000000
dtype: float64
```

If you want a dataframe with an informative column name, use `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="5h")).apply(vwap).reset_index(name="vwap")
```

```
                Dates         vwap
0 2020-09-07 00:00:00  7157.236842
1 2020-09-07 05:00:00  7125.000000
```

Comment: Yup, this got it. I have no idea why it works with grouper and not resample tho.

Comment: That's a good question indeed, would expect resample to work as well. Will try to figure out and post an update here.

Comment: Based on other users who have got the same error, my best guess would be that resample is treating the datetime as a string but Grouper is not. Just a guess though, I'm very much an amateur at this.

Comment: Did you ever work out why this was happening?